# Converting a string representation of a list into an actual list object

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string that looks identical to a list, let's say:

```
fruits = "['apple', 'orange', 'banana']"
```

What would be the way to convert that to a list object?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
>>> fruits = "['apple', 'orange', 'banana']"
>>> import ast
>>> fruits = ast.literal_eval(fruits)
>>> fruits
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
>>> fruits[1]
'orange'
```

As pointed out in the comments [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) is **safe**. From the docs:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the
>   values oneself.

Comment: *Note*: this doesn't work if you call a function inside of the array (or any type except strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None). For these cases, you can use `eval`.

Comment: Note on note: `ast.literal_eval` is successful only for literals and nothing else. It *does protect* your program from code injection, for instance `"['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];import os;os.remove('a_file')"` will fail with `literal_eval`

Comment: I also have same issue but the my string list is like this `fruits = "['apple', 'orange', 'banan'a']"` how would you handle that comma between `banana` and `a`.

Comment: Saved me from getting into strings operations.

Answer (score 36):

A simple call to [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) will do:

```
fruits = eval("['apple', 'orange', 'banana']")
fruits
> ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

Or as explained in this [article](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html), the same can be accomplished a bit more safely (meaning: without risking unintended side-effects or malicious code injections) like this:

```
fruits = eval("['apple', 'orange', 'banana']", {'__builtins__':None}, {})
```

This solution has the advantage of not depending on additional modules.

Comment: This is accomplished a little more safely using `eval(frtstring,{__builtins__:None},{})`

Comment: -1 There is no reason to use `eval()` here. `ast.literal_eval()` will do the job in a much better, safer way.

Comment: Oops, I think it should be `{'__builtins__':None}`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: -1 No need for this hack when you can use `ast`.

Comment: While `ast.literal_eval` is better for this, `eval` works (and it is a useful once in a while so it is worth knowing about).  I don't see any reason to downvote it since it does do what the question asked (+1 from me).

Comment: @mgilson: there are severe security implications to using `eval()`, that even `{'__builtins__': None}` is not going to save you from.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's why I said "a _little_ more safely", but I suppose any discussion in this vein is probably remiss without a link to [Ned's article](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) on exactly why using `{'__builtins__': None}` should be a no-go.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what ast.literal_eval is for.

( http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval )