# Create list of numbers in Python from list-formatted string stored in file

Tags: python, string, list, file, numbers

I have a file that contains a list of numbers in a format exactly how Python would print it. It is a complex list and in the file it looks like this:

```
([(515.51, 615.76), (42.28, 152.3), (223.29, 138.07)], 1)
([(382.27, 502.27), (323.54, 473.01), (212.32, 433.57)], 2)
([(188.74, 442.8), (245.7, 461.47), (391.02, 508.96)], 3)
```

I would like to know how to get it from the file and generate exactly the same list as numbers in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. I am assuming that I have the given data items  in this question in  a file called **data.txt**.

**data.txt**

```
([(515.51, 615.76), (42.28, 152.3), (223.29, 138.07)], 1)
([(382.27, 502.27), (323.54, 473.01), (212.32, 433.57)], 2)
([(188.74, 442.8), (245.7, 461.47), (391.02, 508.96)], 3)
```

**data.py**

```
lists = [];
integers = []

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Each line of file is a tuple with 2 items, first one is list, second one in an integer
        tuple = eval(line.strip());

        # Append each list from each line to lists list
        lists.append(tuple[0]);

        # Append each integer from each line to integers list
        integers.append(tuple[1]);

print(lists);
print(integers);
```

> **Reference:** [Converting a string representation of a list into an actual list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775894/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-list-into-an-actual-list-object)

Comment: It raises me 'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded'.

Comment: Let me check it, I am in mobile so unable to compile. I will respond you soon. Thanks **@tzoukritziu**.

Comment: **@tzoukritziu**, can you please check it now.

Comment: No problem, mistakenly I had used `json.loads()` in place of `eval()`. You also have a look at the reference link in the answer. It will give you the idea of `eval()`.