# Convert dictionary value from string into list with single element of type float

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this: `d = {'a': '[1]', 'b': '[2]'}`. I want to covert the string value into a float and have `d = {'a': [1], 'b': [2]}`, so the value should be a list with a single element of float type. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string representation of a list into an actual list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775894/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-list-into-an-actual-list-object)

Comment: you say float but write ints in your output

Answer (score 2):

```
{k:[float(v.replace(']','').replace('[',''))] for k, v in d.items()}
```

OR

```
{k:[float(v[1,-1])] for k, v in d.items()}
```

`ast.literal_eval` would create a list of int but OP required explicitly a list of float. One could:

```
import ast
{k: [float(a) for a in ast.literal_eval(v)] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for python's [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
d = {'a': '[1]', 'b': '[2]'}
for k in d:
    d[k] = eval(d[k])
print(d)
```

And the output:

```
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
```

### EDIT

As stated in the comments, eval can be sometimes dangerous. So here's an alternative:

```
d = {'a': '[1]', 'b': '[2]'}
for k in d:
    d[k] = [float(d[k][1:-1])] # because the list conatins a single element
print(d)
```

### EDIT2

If you want the alternative to work with lists with multiple values:

replace this line

```
d[k] = [float(d[k][1:-1])]
```

with

```
d[k] = list(map(lambda x: float(x.strip()), d[k][1:-1].split(',')))
```

Comment: "eval" is dangerous, it can execute malicious code and is unnecessary for simple list literals.

Comment: I just added an alternative :)

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Is there a way to have a method that can be extended to a list of multiple objects? So instead of '[1]' I have say '[1, 2]' etc.

Comment: @user12394113 yes, see my last option in my answer

Comment: I just added  and example with lists of multiple objects :)

Answer (score -2):

I will just add a reference to the Python PEP 274 syntactic sugar for this sort of thing, the [Dict Comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> d = {'a': '[1]', 'b': '[2]'}
>>> d = {k: eval(v) for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
```

This is slightly more compact, but works the exact same.

You also made the following note:

> so the value should be a list with a single element of float type.

The above code could be modified to do this easily enough, but I should mention that, for the most part, you can use Python integers anywhere you would want a float.

```
>>> d = {'a': '[1]', 'b': '[2]'}
>>> d = {k: [float(eval(v)[0])] for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d
{'a': [1.0], 'b': [2.0]}
```

### EDIT

I can't reply to your comment because of reputation, JoKing, but it's a great reminder. However, the typical use case for this conversion is probably not fetching source code from potentially malicious 3rd parties and executing it locally. So I would say that, in the case of simple data handling where you control the data io and your source code isn't public or published, `eval()` is absolutely fine.

OP added an additional question in regards to those mentioned dangers of `eval()`:

> So instead of '[1]' I have say '[1, 2]'

If you use previous methods to strip off the brackets, you can use .split(",") to separate the list into individuals strings to be converted. Using the dict comprehension is becoming more ugly here (because it contains a list comprehension to account for this new case), but it still works:

```
>>> d = {'a': '[1, 2]', 'b': '[2]'}
>>> d = {k: [float(i) for i in v[1:-1].split(",")] for k, v in d.items()}
{'a': [1.0, 2.0], 'b': [2.0]}
```

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html