# Convert content of list to integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list which has the following content:

```py
data = ['[1, 2, 3]', '[4, 5, 6]', '[7, 8, 9]']
```

I want convert it into a list of integers in Python3, i.e:

```py
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Is there an elegant and concise way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string representation of a list into an actual list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775894/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-list-into-an-actual-list-object)

Answer (score 1):

You could `eval` each element of your list. however this is not safe as it allows arbitrary code execution.

```
data = [ '[1, 2, 3]' , '[4, 5, 6]' , '[7, 8, 9]' ]
[eval(x) for x in data]
```

A better approach would be to de-serialize using json decoding

```
import json
[json.loads(x) for x in data]
```

Comment: why eval is not safe? I want save the result also in a list

Comment: because eval would evaluate everything. so your data could look like this: `data = [ '[1,2,3]', 'import os; os.system("rm -rf /")']`. guess what happens if you `eval` this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> data = ['[1, 2, 3]', '[4, 5, 6]', '[7, 8, 9]']

>>> list(map(literal_eval, data))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

`ast.literal_eval` is safe, unlike `eval`. Refer [*Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/2063361) for details.

You can also use it with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> [literal_eval(d) for d in data]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```